# How the redis perform when one more progressive rehash trigger

Tags: redis

I've already known redis using progressive way handling rehash, but when the first rehash has not completed, and reached the new apply space rehash point，does the redis start a second rehash? If so, when the data grow fast, the rehash will be unlimit recursion when memory available?

Answer (score 0):

If a rehash is in progress, there won't be a second rehash. New items will be inserted into the new hash table.

The new hash table is about twice the size of the old hash table, and each time we add a new item to the new hash table (or run other operations), we move a bucket from the old table to new table. Normally the new hash won't be *'full'* before Redis finishes rehash, since as more items are added to the new hash table, more buckets are moved to new hash table too.